# Ambient Occlusion - Rendering Artefacts

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, artifacts

I'm trying to render this roof, but I just can't do it without artefacts
It looks okay in the viewport, but the rendering has the black triangles (as in the picture).
I render with Cycles. The ambient occlusion node should just bring some dirt into the corners (The Output Node didn´t make it in the picture ...sorry).
Any suggestions would be very welcome. I am sure that I am doing something wrong. But I don't know what :-) (As always in Blender ;-)

[image: Render Picture vs Viewport].

Comment: Is there a second mash that you have hidden? I suspect that it is hidden in the viewpoint, but it’s showing up in renders, and has the same faces as part of the roof, so when cycles tried to render both faces in the same position, it generates weird looking stuff like this.

Comment: OMG ... thanks ...   Points ... what a shame ... I didn’t realize that my archive is still active... thanks!!

Comment: You’re welcome; God is good! 